# pygame events compatible with pattern matching

Tags: python, pygame, pattern-matching

I am trying to use pattern matching with pygame events, but I get a  `TypeError: called match pattern must be a type`

See example bellow

```
import pygame
import pygame.event

a = pygame.event.Event(0)

def test_match(x):
    match x:
        case pygame.event.Event():
            print('Case Event()', x)
        case pygame.event.Event(type=pygame.USEREVENT):
            print('Case Event(pygame.USEREVENT)', x)
        case _:
            print('not an event')

test_match(a)
```

Full output

```
pygame 2.1.0 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.10.0)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "match_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    test_match(a)
  File "match_test.py", line 8, in test_match
    case pygame.event.Event():
TypeError: called match pattern must be a type
```

Comment: It is waste of time. Use normal if/else

Comment: I don't think so ...
Events can have very different attributes names.
Using if else would result in many nested conditions.
Using match case instead makes something flat and way easier to understand by reading.

Comment: I assum you will have the same number of `case`s as it would have `if`s  - but for me nested version could be more readable. It would group similar conditions in one place.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems it needs `pygame.event.Event` without `()`. It also want work with `pygame.event.Event(type=pygame.USEREVENT)` - even if uses `pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT)`

Comment: *"TypeError: called match pattern must be a type"* - `pygame.event.Event` is a type (it is a class). However `pygame.event.Event()` is not a type. It is an object, an instance object of the class `pygame.event.Event`. Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).

Comment: Thanks I found the solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pygame.event.EventType` in the pattern matching.

```
case pygame.event.EventType(type=pygame.USEREVENT):
```